# chart js radar chart make axes thicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, radar-chart

I have a radar chart with chart.js in MVC Core.net 6.

This is my code:

```
var options = {
    scale: { 
       ticks: { 
       max: 100,
       beginAtZero: true,
       stepSize: 20,
       display: false
       } ,
   },                      
   tooltips: {                          
      callbacks: {
         label: function (tooltipItem, data,) {
             var questionNum =Math.ceil((tooltipItem.yLabel * gtotal[tooltipItem['index']]) / 100);                              
             return  data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label + ": " + questionNum +" From" + gtotal[tooltipItem['index']];                        
           }
     }
   },
    scaleSteps: 5,
    scaleStartValue: 1
  };

 var myRadar =new Chart(ctx, {
                   type: 'radar',
                   data: ChartData,
                   options: options
               });
```

Current output:

[image]

How can I make the axes thicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [doco](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/#grid-lines), you need to set:

For the 'spokes' of the chart:

```
options.scales.r.angleLines.lineWidth
```

And, for the lines connecting the 'spokes':

```
options.scales.r.grid.lineWidth
```

See below for an example:

```js
var options = {
  elements: {
    line: {
      borderWidth: 3
    }
  },
  scales: {
    r: {
      grid: {
        lineWidth: 4
      },
      angleLines: {
        lineWidth: 6
      }
    }
  }
};

var myRadar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'radar',
  data: ChartData,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var ChartData = {
  labels: [
    'Eating',
    'Drinking',
    'Sleeping',
    'Designing',
    'Coding',
    'Cycling',
    'Running'
  ],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First Dataset',
    data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
  }, {
    label: 'My Second Dataset',
    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100],
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'
  }]
};
</script>
```